# Unity POST request failing in sending php data

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine

I am using POST request from Unity to send data to php, that is in the format as given below:

```
IEnumerator Start() {

        WWWForm form = new WWWForm ();
        form.AddField ("token", "ADRE00213wsd");
        
        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post ("localhost/GenerateToken.php", form);
        yield return www.SendWebRequest ();

        if (www.error == null) {
            string responseText = www.downloadHandler.text;
            Debug.Log ("Response Text from the server = " + responseText);
        } else {
            Debug.Log (www.error);
        }
    }
```

And my php is in the format as given below

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();

ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

//Token
$token= htmlspecialchars($_POST["token"]);
...
...
?>
```

This should work right? However I get an error in Unity as response text that is given as `Notice:  Undefined index: token on /var/www/clients/client1/web3/GenerateToken.php on line 10`

Why is this happening with POST method?

Comment: what debugging have you done? try dumping the entire `$_POST`

Comment: I am dumping www.downloadHandler.text which is the response text. What more should I dump`?

Comment: dump the `$_POST` superglobal in your php script before you ry to access the token and see if your unity is posting into php correctly.

Comment: Another thing you can use to test (and remove the client side code from the mix) is a tool like Postman. That lets you construct a POST request and send it to the URL and see the response. One thing to watch for is if a URL redirect is happening. POST data I believe gets lost when a redirect occurs.